# How do I keep leading zeros in Google Sheets after split?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

This is my data:

```
43558#DEYINGCHEN20190403#097855111593#Logitech MX Master Wireless Mouse (910-004337)
```

Then I used `split(#)`. Result:

[image]

The result I want is：`09785111593`

This cell I have formatted into Plain Text, but it failed anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "#", "♦#"), "#"), "♦", ""))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you so much!!!~~you're great!

Answer (score 0):

The way GS remembers to use the output as a string is the apostrophe in front of a number. So in you case you could just simply `SUBSTITUTE()` the `#` by a `#'`:

```
=SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE("'"&A1,"#","#'"),"#")
```

I also concatenated an apostrophe to the start of the string to prevent a possible disappearing leading zero on the first part of your string.